# Allow normal users to configure the TaskScheduler

Tags: windows-task-scheduler, windows-server-2019, administration, non-admin

Is it possible to give normal users such rigths that would allow them to configure the `TaskScheduler` or parts of it (like a single folder) on a `Windows Server`?

---

Background: I need to create & maintain several tasks that would run as a `NetworkService`, but I'm not an admin on that server. I would hover be ok if I had these kind of extended rights.

Comment: Whatever advice we would give, would need an administrator to execute it, and would also give you in effect something close to administrator rights. I suggest you just make the case for your hierarchy to give you admin permissions.

Comment: @harrymc unfortunatelly people here freak out when they hear the words _admin permissions_ so that's pretty much a dead-end. I was hoping there might be some less known policy or whatever registry trick to enable the task-scheduler for prols.

Answer (score 0):

Any registry trick to enable the task-scheduler for a non-admin user
would be a security risk that Microsoft would close immediately.

If you have, or can request, the right to use Hyper-V to create yourself
a virtual machine, you would then be its administrator and could use
the Task Scheduler inside this VM.